# RecentlyViewed not working for Account for portal user

Tags: account, recentlyviewed

recentlviewed not working for Account for portal user

```
listRecent = [SELECT Id, Name,Type FROM RecentlyViewed WHERE type   IN('Contact','Account','Opportunity','Lead') and LastViewedDate !=null    ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC  LIMIT 7 ];
```

query returns value for other object in portal but not for account

Comment: Maybe the user has not viewed any Accounts recently or if the query is running on the portal user's context then Account OWD might play a role here. Can you please check the OWD for Account?

Comment: While analysing this issue more, I found that recentlyviewd list is not updating while view the account record, I tried by removing limit and printing the record in debug log